# Compare 2 dataframes if both zero return NA in both original dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

**Create dataframe**

```
df_a <- data.frame(locus = c('1_1','1_2','1_3','1_4'), sample1 = c(10,NA,15,0), sample2 = c(5,10,NA,0), sample3 = c(0,NA,20,10), sample4 = c(5,NA,20,10), row.names = 1)
df_b <- data.frame(locus = c('1_1','1_2','1_3','1_4'), sample1 = c(8,NA,15,0), sample2 = c(NA,30,15,0), sample3 <- c(22,NA,40,10), sample4 = c(0,NA,12,30), row.names = 1)
```

**Desire result**

```
df_a_result <- data.frame(locus = c('1_1','1_2','1_3','1_4'), sample1 = c(10,NA,15,NA), sample2 = c(5,10,NA,NA), sample3 = c(0,NA,20,10), sample4 = c(5,NA,20,10), row.names = 1)
df_b_result <- data.frame(locus = c('1_1','1_2','1_3','1_4'), sample1 = c(8,NA,15,NA), sample2 = c(NA,30,15,NA), sample3 <- c(22,NA,40,10), sample4 = c(0,NA,12,30), row.names = 1)
```

If same cell positions in both dataframes return 0,0 then replace 0 with NA in both original dataframes

**This what I tried**

```
df_a_result <- df_a[df_a[,] + df_b[,] == 0] <- "NA"
```

In Excel, I would use this formula for each cell then replicate this for every cell in df_a then repeat in df_b

=IF(df_a!B2<>"NA", IF(df_a!B2+df_b!B2=0,"NA",df_a!B2),df_a!B2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible way to solve your problem using built-in functions `Map` and `ifelse`:

```
cases <- Map(function(x, y) x==0 & y==0, df_a, df_b)   # returns TRUE if corresponding cells are both 0
df_a[] <- Map(ifelse, cases, NA, df_a)                 # replace TRUE cases with NA in df_a
df_b[] <- Map(ifelse, cases, NA, df_b)                 # replace TRUE cases with NA in df_b


df_a

    sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4
1_1      10       5       0       5
1_2      NA      10      NA      NA
1_3      15      NA      20      20
1_4      NA      NA      10      10

df_b
    sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4
1_1       8      NA      22       0
1_2      NA      30      NA      NA
1_3      15      15      40      12
1_4      NA      NA      10      30
```

Answer (score 0):

use this `for loop`

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df_a)){
  for(j in seq_along(df_a)){
    df_a[i,j] <- ifelse(df_a[i,j] == 0 & df_a[i,j] == df_b[i,j], NA, df_a[i,j])
    df_b[i,j] <- ifelse(df_b[i,j] == 0 & df_a[i,j] == df_b[i,j], NA, df_b[i,j])
  }
}
```

Results

```
> df_a
    sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4
1_1      10       5       0       5
1_2      NA      10      NA      NA
1_3      15      NA      20      20
1_4      NA      NA      10      10
> df_b
    sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4
1_1       8      NA      22       0
1_2      NA      30      NA      NA
1_3      15      15      40      12
1_4      NA      NA      10      30
```